# Correlation between chemical analysis results

Tags: correlation, multivariate-analysis, chemometrics

I have performed chemical analysis on a sample and the resulting data is something like this: "Carbon: 1.2%, Iron: 50%, Vanadium 2.3% ..." and so on.

I have 25 sets of similar data taken from other samples and I need to figure out which of these 25 sets matches the first one the best i.e., which has the closest chemical composition to the sample.

This is probably a very simple problem but I have not studied statistics. I tried to use Pearson correlation but I'm not sure this is the right tool for this specific problem.

Comment: Clustering? or better, graphical methods. Make a plot with the relative percentages? Or look into "compositional methods" which was made for this kind of situation.  Or, maybe some kind of correspondence analysis could be used!

Comment: You could also post your data as a table in the original post. Could be interesting to have a look!

Comment: Have a look at:  http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9781119976462.ch8/summary